# Launch the app with Options or With Custom URL scheme after installing from iTunes

Tags: ios, url-scheme, launching-application, itunes-store, custom-url

Is it possible to navigate user to specific screen of our app when he/she installs the app from a link to iTunes Store.

let's suppose i shared a link of our app to some friend via email, if the app is already installed on his/her device then our app will be launched via custom url scheme, but if app is not already installed then he will be redirected to iTunes store along with additional parameters that will be used in first run of the app, and after successful installation of app it should be launched options which were  passed in parameters of itunes link.

Steps:
URL Clicked app-->App not installed so open it in safari-->Server will redirect to itunes link of app along with launch options as additional parameters-->Goto iTunes to download & install App --> Launch the app via LaunchOptions or Custom URL Scheme --> Process Launch Options and navigate to appropriate screen

Comment: there are multiple ways to do so. One of them is to detect whether the custom url is open-able by JavaScript. If not, redirect to iTunes store.

Comment: How exactly do you test if the custom url is open-able using javascript?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: can you elaborate plz..
 
actually my specific question is  : what if we redirect to iTunes store then how to pass additional parameters to it's url so that it can be used in the first launch of app?

Comment: the URL has to be re-clicked. iTunes won't accept parameters.

Comment: Some keywords for any one still have this problem: 1. deferred deeplink 2. onboarding links

Comment: you need to use deeplink ..